# How to make a Joomla+VirtueMart site load faster?

Tags: php, joomla, gzip, minify, joomla-extensions

Is there any Joomla extension that can minify and merge all CSS and all JavaScript together?

Also is there an extension to use a CDN (cloudfront) for all static files?

Finally, how to optimize the images? There are some huge images that weight almost 5 MB (!!), how can I get them to be resized to the correct display size?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the [Sire Performance](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance) category on JED

Comment: @Lodder thanks! Gave you a +1

Answer (score 1):

Try these things too,

- Enable compression from C panel
- All the images compressed with [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) or pngout
- Enable page expiry using header or htaccess.
- You can use Joomla caching plugins too.
- In additionally you can try some CDN for server caching
- Minimize all your css and js files

This will help your site speed definitely..

Hope its helps..

Answer (score 1):

1. I think that VirtueMart has problem when there is bigger amount of products (1000 and more). The problem is in not so optimized SQL queries. [Here is quite clever solution for caching](http://www.easyjoomla.org/speeding-up-virtuemart-2-0-joomla-e-commerce-site-case-study).
2. You can find some performance plugins at [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance). Some functions will destroy your web so test it at test environment first. We use [Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) in our projects and it works fine. But you need to configure server for it and that could be a problem at some public webhosting.
3. Also you can find some [CDN extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/content-networking). We tried few of them last months but in the end we switched them off. It works fine when you do not update your web. When you do, there is problem that every user looks at different version of the web with different version of CSS and JS which usually means destroyed web. We didn't figured out how to reset CDN after update yet.